# Getting "Rejecting deliver request for IP:port because of consenter" error with raft

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

I'm running a multi-org setup on cloud consists of `2 Orgs`, `4 Peers(2 peers per Org)` and `3 ordering nodes`. All the peer nodes and the node `orderer0` are running on `DigitalOcean droplet`. `orderer2` and `orderer3` nodes are running on `AWS` and `GCP` respectively. For `ordering service` I'm using `Raft` and `orderer2` was selected as a `Leader`. For creating the `channel`, `installing/instantiating/querying` the chaincode, I'm executing a `scripts.sh`(present in byfn under scripts directory) on the peer. The script executed successfully i.e channel was created(using orderer0 node), joined by all the peers and installation/instantiation/query of chaincode executed successfully. But when I checked the `orderer0` logs I found below errors.

> 2019-11-15 13:33:08.814 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 04a [channel: mychannel] Rejecting deliver request for 139.59.7.201:59304 because of consenter error
>
> 2019-11-15 13:33:08.815 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04b streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=139.59.7.201:59304 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=201.373401ms

After a few seconds

> 2019-11-15 13:33:09.654 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 058 raft.node: 1 elected leader 2 at term 2 channel=mychannel node=1
>
> 2019-11-15 13:33:09.657 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] serveRequest -> INFO 059 Raft leader changed: 0 -> 2 channel=mychannel node=1
>
> 2019-11-15 13:33:09.865 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 05a Error reading from 139.59.7.201:59314: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

**docker-compose-orderer.yaml**

```
version: '2'

networks: 
  byfn:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - ORDERER_HOST=orderer.example.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=OrdererOrg
      - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ADDRESSES=[127.0.0.1:7050]

        # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.key
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:139.59.13.3"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:139.59.13.119"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:139.59.7.201"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:139.59.24.225"
      - "orderer2.example.com:3.14.67.48"
      - "orderer3.example.com:34.69.118.13"

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./channel-artifacts/:/var/hyperledger/configs
      - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users:/var/hyperledger/users
        #- orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks: 
      - byfn
```

**docker-compose-orderer2.yaml**

```
version: '2'

networks: 
  byfn:

services:

  orderer2.example.com:
    container_name: orderer2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - ORDERER_HOST=orderer2.example.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=OrdererOrg
      - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ADDRESSES=[127.0.0.1:7050]

        # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.key
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:139.59.13.3"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:139.59.13.119"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:139.59.7.201"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:139.59.24.225"
      - "orderer.example.com:139.59.1.164"
      - "orderer2.example.com:3.14.67.48"
      - "orderer3.example.com:34.69.118.13"

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./channel-artifacts/:/var/hyperledger/configs
      - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users:/var/hyperledger/users
        #- orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks: 
      - byfn
```

**docker-compose-orderer3.yaml**

```
version: '2'

networks: 
  byfn:

services:

  orderer3.example.com:
    container_name: orderer3.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - ORDERER_HOST=orderer3.example.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=OrdererOrg
      - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ADDRESSES=[127.0.0.1:7050]

        # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.key
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:139.59.13.3"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:139.59.13.119"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:139.59.7.201"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:139.59.24.225"
      - "orderer.example.com:139.59.1.164"
      - "orderer2.example.com:3.14.67.48"
      - "orderer3.example.com:34.69.118.13"

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./channel-artifacts/:/var/hyperledger/configs
      - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users:/var/hyperledger/users
        #- orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks: 
      - byfn
```

**docker-compose-orderer.yaml**

```
version: '2'

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - ORDERER_HOST=orderer.example.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=OrdererOrg
      - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ADDRESSES=[127.0.0.1:7050]

        # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      #- ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.crt
      - ORDERER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/users/Admin@example.com/tls/client.key
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go

    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:139.59.13.3"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:139.59.13.119"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:139.59.7.201"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:139.59.24.225"
      - "orderer2.example.com:3.14.67.48"
      - "orderer3.example.com:34.69.118.13"

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./channel-artifacts/:/var/hyperledger/configs
      - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users:/var/hyperledger/users
        #- orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - byfn
```

orderer(orderer0) node logs
https://justpaste.it/49a1n

Orderer2 node logs ae huge hence sharing the link
https://justpaste.it/6ro0v

orderer3 logs
https://justpaste.it/5e4j8

peer0org1 logs
https://justpaste.it/33rm5

peer1org1 logs
https://justpaste.it/1s2uz

peer0org2 logs
https://justpaste.it/6emlk

peer1org2 logs
https://justpaste.it/53fna

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: There are couple of reasons:-
1. When the leader selection process(raft leader) is going on and if orderer node receives a txn then it rejected it because currently there's is no leader to execute that txn hence it started showing consenter error.

2. the connection between the orderer nodes isn't right. to debug this use `nc -vz IP port` command to check the connections between the nodes(assuming all the nodes running on a separate VM). Here IP is the public/private IP and port is orderer port

Comment: Did you find the cause? Could it be because the sender wasn't being authorized: maybe the sender's private key was not where it should be? Or the private key was changed, perhaps.